# Classic Asterisk Pyramid Exercise, with a twist

Tags: loops

This is one of those typical asterisk exercises, but it has several things that are making it a problem for me.

Example of what should happen when there's invalid input:

```
Input an odd number from 1 to 9: 4
The number 4 is invalid. 
Input an odd number from 1 to 9:
```

Example of what should happen when there's valid input:

```
Input an odd number from 1 to 9: 5
   *
  ***
 *****
```

It's supposed to be a triangle, where the base has n asterisks, n being the input of the user.

I have been messing around with while and for loops for hours and the best I've gotten was the error message. I can't get it to repeat, nor can I make this pyramid.

Thanks,
A friendly rookie programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. If you still wanna answer, feel free!